# Where can I find a human anatomy dataset that is easy to read/use programmatically

Tags: dataset, rdf, owl

I am looking for a dataset of human anatomy, that gives me the hierachacal relationships between the body parts/bones/muscles.

I have found data sets such as [UMLS](https://uts.nlm.nih.gov///home.html) and [GALEN](http://www.opengalen.org/) which are large RDF/OWL data sets that give me this sort of data but I have found getting the subset of data I want out quite difficult - mainly due to the lack of .NET libraries/tooling for OWL and my lack of knowledge of this area.

I'm confident I will eventually be able to get something out of them if needs be but I was wondering if anyone knows of a smaller/simpler data set. We are willing to pay for it if necessary as time is critical.

Something like below but for the whole body (we can be quite flexible here...we just need it small/simple)

```
<Arm>
  <Bones>
      <Humerus/>
      <Raduius/>
      <Ulna/>
  </Bones>
  <Muscles>
   ...
  </Muscles>
</Arm>
```

I have searched the web for something like this and found nothing at this level of simplicity but with the necessary detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FMA ontology and data triples: http://sig.biostr.washington.edu/share/downloads/fma/release/latest/fma.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Foundational Model of Anatomy is available in mysql - it might not be quite as simple as you want, though.
http://sig.biostr.washington.edu/projects/fm/index.html

The FAQ has instructions for installation:
http://sig.biostr.washington.edu/projects/fma/release/v3.2.1/FMA_instructions.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll download and have a look. Having it in a DB will be a real help I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

**Snomed** anatomy : http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/43050?p=terms&jump_to_nav=true&conceptid=http%3A%2F%2Fihtsdo.org%2Fsnomedct%2Fanatomy%23119525000

**Foundational Model of Anatomy** : http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/39991?p=terms&jump_to_nav=true&conceptid=FMA%3A13303

(... see also the whole bioportal: http://bioportal.bioontology.org )

Answer (score 1):

Also in http://sparql.bioontology.org/ the graph `<http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/FMA>` contains the RDF content of FMA.

Comment: Is it possible to download content or data implements Ontologies in BioPortal ?

Comment: It depends on the license of the particular ontologies. Most of them are downloadable in the original format, RDF and CSV